# Changing the placement of the left border of tables in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, border

Is it possible to have tables in Word such that the border lines align with the text outside the table?

In MS Word, the left-side (and also the right-side) border is by default not aligned with the rest of the text on a page. It's actually the text in the first column of a table that is aligned with the text outside the table. And the table border is a little bit to the left. I find this layout quite a bit annoying, as I don't want to have any elements on  a page outside the range that is used by normal text.

I know that I can change the column delimiters manually (via the ruler). I'm looking for some more automatic way like setting the defaults for the whole document or such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, figure out what style is applied to tables by default. This depends on the version of Word as well as what customizations (if any) have been made; on my computer, it's "Table Grid". Then, open your default template (normal.dot) and modify that style to apply a .08" indent to the entire table (under Table Properties).

Note that the .08" measurement is the default cell margin. If you've changed that to a different number, make sure your table indent matches the changed value.

Note also that this only fixes the left margin of tables. I don't know of a way to automatically affect the right margin as well.